# AVPlayer Autoplay

Tags: macos, avplayer

How to make avplayer in osx autoplay?

I've tried this:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
URLForResource:@"video name" withExtension:@"mp4"];
self.movieView.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
```

it doesn't autoplay?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't called the play method.

```
[self.movieView.player play]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think, AVplayer first check the URL content is available or not. You must add observer on it.

```
 [avplayerObject addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

#pragma Observer for Player status.
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == _audioPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (_audioPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");
            loader.hidden = true;
        } else if (_audioPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
                [_audioPlayer play];

        } else if (_audioPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");

        }
        [_audioPlayer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:nil];
    }

}
```